# Error while using GooglePlus ionic-native

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am trying to use `Google Plus - Ionic-native`. I have done everything like adding plugin + ionic-native + reverseClientId.

But when I try to build `apk` using `ionic cordova build android --prod` I am getting error :

> Could not find play-services-auth.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0)

Comment: I think you should add more error information

Comment: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus#9-troubleshooting do you have "Android Support Repository and Android Support Library" installed?

Answer (score 0):

For android platform 
in `config.xml`:
You need to add the reverse client Id & the web application Id like this:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-googleplus" spec="^5.2.1">
    <variable name="REVERSED_CLIENT_ID" value="com.googleusercontent.apps.588101161325-dsfgdfgergregergergg4ha72kbfn1l0" />
    <variable name="WEB_APPLICATION_CLIENT_ID" value="588101161325-f3p5ufdgsdfgsdfgsdfgdfgsdfgdfgfgg.apps.googleusercontent.com" />
</plugin>
```